# PayPal IPN returns "INVALID" even though payment was processed

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

**FAILED REQUEST**

> request:cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=2.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LDYM496TZ5PMS&tax=0.00&address_street=7
>   Malcom Ave Quarrington Hill&payment_date=10:56:23 Jul 10, 2014
>   PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=DH6
>   4QT&first_name=fake&mc_fee=0.38&address_country_code=GB&address_name=fake
>   fake&notify_version=3.8&custom=168&payer_status=unverified&business=fake@gmail.com&address_country=United
>   Kingdom&address_city=Durham&quantity=0&verify_sign=AO3SqMqkkL6g6znCfk.bTx0YGc9QAAC62A.uYD2AR27aMUKA8tjOenQg&payer_email=fake@gmail.com&txn_id=0V51470288084925M&payment_type=instant&last_name=fake&address_state=&receiver_email=fake@gmail.com&payment_fee=0.38&receiver_id=43PTLVVM58JD4&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Hyubusa&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=GB&transaction_subject=168&payment_gross=2.00&ipn_track_id=8f6ab718d71f2

**Failed POST**

> mc_gross=2.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LDYM496TZ5PMS&tax=0.00&address_street=7+Malcom+Ave%0D%0AQuarrington+Hill&payment_date=10%3A56%3A23+Jul+10%2C+2014+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=DH6+4QT&first_name=fake&mc_fee=0.38&address_country_code=GB&address_name=fake+fake&notify_version=3.8&custom=168&payer_status=unverified&business=fake%40gmail.com&address_country=United+Kingdom&address_city=Durham&quantity=0&verify_sign=AO3SqMqkkL6g6znCfk.bTx0YGc9QAAC62A.uYD2AR27aMUKA8tjOenQg&payer_email=fake%40gmail.com&txn_id=0V51470288084925M&payment_type=instant&last_name=fake&address_state=&receiver_email=adamhyubusa%40gmail.com&payment_fee=0.38&receiver_id=43PTLVVM58JD4&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Hyubusa&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=GB&transaction_subject=168&payment_gross=2.00&ipn_track_id=8f6ab718d71f2

So, my PayPal IPN is returning an INVALID response SOMETIMES! ... When I test it on sandbox it works fine. When I test it with my own CC it works fine.

Occasionally when I get a donation however, the money comes through ... but the response from IPN is invalid.

I am in the US ... the particular donator it is currently failing on is from the UK ... I do not know if that has any relevance. This is my code.

```
$request = "cmd=_notify-validate"; 
foreach ($_POST as $varname => $varvalue){
$email .= "$varnamefake: $varvalue\n";  
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') and get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  
    $varvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($varvalue)); 
}
else { 
    $value = urlencode($value); 
} 
$request .= "&$varname=$varvalue"; 
} 

$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
switch($result){
    case "VERIFIED":
        $message = "good: $".$_POST['mc_gross']." | ".$_POST['custom'];
        $amt = str_replace("$", "", $_POST['mc_gross']);
        $data = array(
               'STATUS' => 1,
               'AMOUNT' => $amt
        );

        $this->db->where('ID', $_POST['custom']);
        $this->db->update('donations', $data);        

    case "INVALID":
        $message ="bad";
        mail("fakeemail@fake.com","paypal response", $message);
        break;
    default:
        $message ="other";
        mail("fakeemail@fake.com","paypal response", $message);
}
```

**FAILED REQUEST**

> request:cmd=_notify-validate&mc_gross=2.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LDYM496TZ5PMS&tax=0.00&address_street=7
>   Malcom Ave Quarrington Hill&payment_date=10:56:23 Jul 10, 2014
>   PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=DH6
>   4QT&first_name=fake&mc_fee=0.38&address_country_code=GB&address_name=Brendan
>   fake&notify_version=3.8&custom=168&payer_status=unverified&business=fake@gmail.com&address_country=United
>   Kingdom&address_city=Durham&quantity=0&verify_sign=AO3SqMqkkL6g6znCfk.bTx0YGc9QAAC62A.uYD2AR27aMUKA8tjOenQg&payer_email=fake@gmail.com&txn_id=0V51470288084925M&payment_type=instant&last_name=Watson&address_state=&receiver_email=fake@gmail.com&payment_fee=0.38&receiver_id=43PTLVVM58JD4&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Hyubusa&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=GB&transaction_subject=168&payment_gross=2.00&ipn_track_id=8f6ab718d71f2

**Failed POST**

> mc_gross=2.00&protection_eligibility=Eligible&address_status=confirmed&payer_id=LDYM496TZ5PMS&tax=0.00&address_street=7+Malcom+Ave%0D%0AQuarrington+Hill&payment_date=10%3A56%3A23+Jul+10%2C+2014+PDT&payment_status=Completed&charset=windows-1252&address_zip=DH6+4QT&first_name=fake&mc_fee=0.38&address_country_code=GB&address_name=fake+fake&notify_version=3.8&custom=168&payer_status=unverified&business=fake%40gmail.com&address_country=United+Kingdom&address_city=Durham&quantity=0&verify_sign=AO3SqMqkkL6g6znCfk.bTx0YGc9QAAC62A.uYD2AR27aMUKA8tjOenQg&payer_email=fake%40gmail.com&txn_id=0V51470288084925M&payment_type=instant&last_name=Watson&address_state=&receiver_email=adamhyubusa%40gmail.com&payment_fee=0.38&receiver_id=43PTLVVM58JD4&txn_type=web_accept&item_name=Hyubusa&mc_currency=USD&item_number=&residence_country=GB&transaction_subject=168&payment_gross=2.00&ipn_track_id=8f6ab718d71f2

Comment: Can you provide a raw dump of the POST data PayPal sends you as well as a raw dump of the string you're generating and sending back to them when it fails?  They must not match for some reason.  My guess would be something to do with URL encoding or special characters in the data on particular orders.

Comment: This is how the failed request looks: ... posted in main question

Comment: Yeah, you can see that they're different.  One is URL encoded and the other is not.  You need to get that situated so you send it back to PayPal exactly as they sent it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') and get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  
    $varvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($varvalue)); 
}
else { 
    $value = urlencode($value); 
}
```

IPN variables are already url encoded, no point of encoding them again to send back to paypal - probably the reason why some transactions work and others don't.

Comment: Thanks ... that seems to have fixed it... need some more live testing but it seems to work, thank you.